# scriptfile can't be reached

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am currently trying to put some of my script on a .js file, but it seem i can't acced it. i included it using the folowing line. i already check the path, and the permission

```
 <script src="../static/js/usefullScript.js"></script>
```

here is the content of the.js file, who work without any probleme when put in a `<script>` tag on an html page

```
( function( factory ) {
    if ( typeof define === "function" && define.amd ) {

        // AMD. Register as an anonymous module.
        define( [ "../widgets/datepicker" ], factory );
    } else {

        // Browser globals
        factory( jQuery.datepicker );
    }
}( function( datepicker ) {

    datepicker.regional[ "fr-CA" ] = {
        closeText: "Fermer",
        prevText: "Précédent",
        nextText: "Suivant",
        currentText: "Aujourd'hui",
        monthNames: [ "janvier", "février", "mars", "avril", "mai", "juin",
            "juillet", "août", "septembre", "octobre", "novembre", "décembre" ],
        monthNamesShort: [ "janv.", "févr.", "mars", "avril", "mai", "juin",
            "juil.", "août", "sept.", "oct.", "nov.", "déc." ],
        dayNames: [ "dimanche", "lundi", "mardi", "mercredi", "jeudi", "vendredi", "samedi" ],
        dayNamesShort: [ "dim.", "lun.", "mar.", "mer.", "jeu.", "ven.", "sam." ],
        dayNamesMin: [ "D", "L", "M", "M", "J", "V", "S" ],
        weekHeader: "Sem.",
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        firstDay: 0,
        isRTL: false,
        showMonthAfterYear: false,
        yearSuffix: ""
    };
    datepicker.setDefaults( datepicker.regional[ "fr-CA" ] );

    return datepicker.regional[ "fr-CA" ];

} ) );
```

and the console of the programme give me this warning

> Loading failed for the  with source “http://localhost:8080/static/js/usefullScript.js”.

Comment: have you tried linking this way /serverroot/static/js/usefullScript.js instead of ../static/js/usefullScript.js

Comment: it ain't working either

Comment: what happens when you try <script type="text/javascript" src="../static/js/usefullScript.js"></script>, you're defining "text/javascript"

Comment: trying this line aint working either.